# Comments plugin - only display comments from last x days

Tags: facebook, plugins, comments

Is there a way to display only the last couple of days in the comments plugin embedded in a page tab? The rest to be available in some sort of archive.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such functionality in the "Comments Social Plugin" itself but you can mimic it to be close to what you want, since you can get the comments via Graph API or FQL and can limit number of posts displayed in the plugin.